# Using Highcharts Export Server, how to include commas in labels?

Tags: javascript, java, highcharts

I am creating a Highcharts configuration object in Java (EDIT: yes, Java, on the server side, NOT JavaScript), and sending it to the Highcharts Export Server to get a PNG to use in a PDF.

Highcharts, by default, doesn't include commas in its data labels.

If I were just creating this chart on the client side, I'd add this to the javascript:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

Then, I could make the commas show up.

The problem is, I don't know how to send an equivalent message to the Highcharts Export Server. Currently, I am sending an object like this (EDIT: from the server side, using Java) to the Highcharts Export Server and not getting commas in the labels of the PNG it returns:

```
{
    series: [{
        data: [1000, 2000, 1500],
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do or send to the Highcharts Export Server to get the desired effect of putting commas in the labels?

(you can test out objects in the Highcharts Export Server here: http://export.highcharts.com/)

Comment: The Highcharts object, which is essentially a string to Java, is created in Java on the server side, and the export server is accessed via Java.

Comment: Fair enough, and thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can you `globalOptions` parameter in your request to achieve the desired result.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0s7uwsgg/

```
var optionsStr = JSON.stringify({
    "series": [{
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: 'true'
      },
      "data": [1000, 1000]
    }]
  }),
  globalOptions = JSON.stringify({
    lang: {
          thousandsSep: ','
    }
  }),
  dataString = encodeURI('async=true&type=jpeg&width=400&options=' + optionsStr + '&globalOptions=' + globalOptions);
```

**API reference for request parameters:** https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md